# Orbits of the action of $SL(n,\mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

Tags: group-actions, general-linear-group

We know that $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$ via left multiplication. We can easily see that there are two orbits viz $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$. Now we also know that if $G$ acts on $X$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $H$ acts on $X$ and the $H$-orbits are actually suborbits of the $G$-orbits. Now I want to know what are the orbits of the action of $SL(n,\mathbb R)$  on $\mathbb R^n$. Does it subdivide the orbit of non-zero vectors further into smaller suborbits?

Comment: Consider the sets of all upper triangular matrices with ones-diagonal, and lower triangular matrices with ones-diagonal. Can you write an explicit formula for how they act on a vector? From this, can you make an argument for how $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ acts?

Comment: @William I still cannot get it.

Comment: @William I think for $n=2$,there are only two orbits $\mathbb R^2-\{0\}$ and $\{0\}$ because the non-zero vectors are in the orbit of $e_1$.Because,for $(a,b)\neq 0 (0,0)$ a vector in $\mathbb R^2$ ,I can use the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0\\b&\frac{1}{a}\\\end{pmatrix}$ or  $\begin{pmatrix} a & -\frac{1}{b}\\b&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ to go from $e_1$ to $(a,b)$.

Comment: but I can't say anything for $n>2$.

Comment: Following @William's comment, transvections, which are particular triangular matrices, if $n>1$ generate $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Think about how transvections acts on vectors.

Comment: @Davide Please write an answer....I cannot understand.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the action of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ via left multiplication.

If $n=1$, then $SL(1,\mathbb{R})\cong\{1\}$ and the action is trivial.

We will study $n=2$, the case $n>2$ is equal with some dots around. Take a generic vector $\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}\ne\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. We see this vector is in the same orbit of $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$.

If $y\ne0$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\y&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\y \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&\frac{x-1}{y}\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}.$$

If $y=0$, then $x\ne 0$ and
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&x-1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x\\1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\-\frac{1}{x}&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x\\0 \end{pmatrix}
.$$

So if $n\ge2$ the orbits are exactly the orbits of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Those kind of matrices that allow you to do operations with the rows of a vector are called *shear matrices* or *transvections*. They differ from the identity matrix only for an element which doesn't lie in the diagonal and if $n\ge 2$ they generate $SL(n,\mathbb{F})$ in any field $\mathbb{F}$.